# Series with parametric value

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have some problem with this parametric series:
$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty n^\alpha\left(\frac 1{n^{1/4}}-\sin\left(\frac 1{n^{1/4}}\right)\right) $

which value of $\alpha$ makes the series convergent? And which divergent?

Answer (score 2):

$\sin x\sim x-x^3/6$ as $x\to0$. Then
$$
n^{-1/4}-\sin(n^{-1/4})\sim\frac16\,n^{-3/4}\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty.
$$
Can yo finish?

Comment: so i have $\sum_1^\infty \frac16n^{\alpha-3/4}$  so if $\alpha$ is $<-\frac14$

Comment: Yes, both series have the same behavior by the comparison criterium (they are positive series.)

Comment: so i have $\sum_1^\infty \frac16n^{\alpha-3/4}$  so if $\alpha$ is $<-\frac14$ the series is convergent and instead if $\alpha$ is $> -\frac14$

Comment: is it right? for $\alpha < -\frac14$ is it convergent?

Comment: That is correct.